# The pipe 'orderBy' could not be found error coming when using with async

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, observable

I am trying to use orderBy pipe in ngFor with async pipe. But it is giving following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'orderBy' could not be found ("
          </div>
          <div
            *ngFor="let a of arr | async | orderBy: 'b': ng:///TestModule/TestComponent.html@95:34
Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'orderBy' could not be found ("
          </div>
          <div
```

arr returns observables, it is working fine without orderBy, but when I want to use orderBy it is giving error:

```
<div *ngFor="let a of arr | async | orderBy: 'b'> </div>
```

Comment: Angular doaesn't have any pipe named orderBy (and strongly discourage creating one). Did you define one? Why do you think this should work? Are you confusing Angular with AngularJS? Those are two distinct frameworks.

Comment: @JBNizet can we use async pipe?

Comment: Yes, you can. What would be the point of defining a pipe that you can't use? Here is the page where you can look for documentation on Angular. Please do. https://angular.io/

Comment: @JBNizet Could you please help me in ways to send data after async pipe and sort the results so that I can display them in custom order. Is there a way other than creating custom pipe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to recommend you DON'T sort via a custom pipe. Angular took the orderBy pipe out for a reason, because it is generally inefficient in it's execution. You're working with an observable stream anyway, so why not just add the sort as an operator in your component like this?

```
this.arr = this.arr.pipe(map(arr => arr.sort((a,b) => a > b))); // really any sort logic you want
```

this guarantees sorting only occcurs when it really needs to occur, IE, when the array is changed. Then you don't need to use any pipes, and you can keep your sort actions in code where they really belong.

Comment: @bryn60 Do you suggest to subscribe to the observables within the component rather using async pipe?

Comment: no, continue using the async pipe.  but just add a map operator in the chain that does the sort for you rather than relying on a sort pipe.

Comment: return observable
      .pipe(map(documents =>
        _.sortBy(
          documents,
          (document) => document.startDate)));

Comment: The above code is not sorting the data though no errors in console. Am I doing something wrong here.

Comment: SortBy of underscore was working within subscribe method.

Comment: Its working with sort. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Not like AngularJS, Angular 2+ had [stopped support serveral build in pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).

You must define a custom pipe in order to use one:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'yourPipeName'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  // The pipe's transform method take first Argurment is the data using that 
  // pipe( which is data before the '|' mark in the template), the others 
  // parameter is optional

  // Your sort logic is in here
  transform(input: Array<any>, para1, para2) {
    return input.sort( (a,b) => a>b);
  }
}
```

Then you should declare the newly created pipe in your module and you will able to use it in your template like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let a of arr | async | yourPipeName> </div>
```

Comment: Can we use async piped results to this custom pipe, does it send the array of data or array of observables to the custom pipe.

Comment: Yes it does, it work like a normal pipe which can have one or mutiple pipe following the data